# Changing ownership of a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chown

I am trying to change the ownership of a directory to a certain group.
I execute `getent group` and I see that the group I'm interested is in there - `sudo:x:27`.
Now I am executing chown in the following way:
`sudo chown -R sudo /PATH/TO/DIR`
And I get: `id 'sudo': no such user`
I also tried `sudo chown -R 27 /PATH/TO/DIR` - this commands actually being executed but then when I try for example to use `mkdir` in the directory I should own right now I get `permission denied` (and I did check with `ls -l` that the permissions changed).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chown takes the user and group as `user:group`. If you only want to change the group:

```
sudo chown -R :sudo /PATH/TO/DIR
```

Comment: (OT: sorry for the edit back and forth, I had a little trouble with the history of my browser)

Comment: And this way this group will keep all of it's past ownerships right? nothing changes except from the added ownership?

Comment: no, this will replace the current group of all subdirectories and files under that directory with the group `group`. Your question states that you want to CHANGE the group, not ADD another one.

Comment: Oh so I am probably using the wrong command? I simply want a specific directory to be owned by the `sudo` group (so if im inside that group I can create/delete/copy files inside that folder)- is there another command that does this?

Comment: This command does this. It **will** change the owning group. It will **not** change permissions. It will **not** change the owning user.

Comment: What's wrong with the right command for the situation, `chgrp`?

Comment: Nothing. As usual there is more than one way to do something in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chgrp command.  ie.

```
sudo chgrp -R /PATH/TO/DIR
```

Using `chown` will work with names or numbers... ie. specifying `27` would have worked if you had also specified the username/UID correctly. For example:

```
sudo chown -R 0:27 /PATH/TO/DIR
```

would have set the ownership to `root:sudo`.

If you just want to change the group, `chgrp` may be easier for you.

If you only want to change a single directory, ie the one specified, omit the -R option.

If you want to change permissions, use the `chmod` command.